# Does TargetNullValue work identically in WPF and Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, targetnullvalue

Recently, TargetNullValue support has been added to XF, but the description is different from the description in WPF. Is this just a mistake in the description, but they work in the same way?

**WPF**

[Gets or sets the value that is used in the target **when the value of the source** is null.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.targetnullvalue)

**Xamarin.Forms**

[Gets or sets the value to supply for a bound property **when the target** of the binding is null.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=xamarin-forms)

*If they work identically, then the description of operation in WPF is more precise and reflects the sense of operation, while the description in XF introduces confusion.*

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms description doesn't seem to make much sense. What happens when you just try it out?

Comment: And after @Clemens suggestion, you can head over to the Microsoft Docs repository and change it yourself ;)

Comment: But I do not ask where to change it and where to report it. I ask if they act the same.

Comment: "I ask if they act the same" - What exactly stops you from trying it out?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I checked it and in XF it works in the same way as in WPF. This means that in XF, the description is simply incorrect.

**TargetNullValue**

```
<Label BindingContext="{Binding Employee}" Text="{Binding Path=Name, TargetNullValue='Hello'}" />
```

**Source (with null)**

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                Raise();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Raise([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**The word "Hello" appears in Label.Text**